# replacing str in columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, replace

I have to replace some values like follow but I'm not getting values to replace as I want

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
pd.set_option('display.max_columns',None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows',None)

df=pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls',skiprows=17, skipfooter=265-(227))
df.drop(df.columns[[0,1]], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.columns=['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable']
replace_values={"Republic of Korea": "South Korea",
"United States of America": "United States",
"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom",
"China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong"}
df['Country']=df['Country'].str.replace(replace_values)
df
```

Comment: What's the issue? What's the expected output vs. the output you're getting?

Comment: Should it be df['Country']=df['Country'].replace(replace_values) instead?

Comment: I'm not getting any change in values

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work no?

```
df['Country'].replace(["Republic of Korea", "South Korea"],["United States of America", "United States"],
["United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", "United Kingdom"],
["China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region", "Hong Kong"], inplace=True)
```